# How to show counts in separate columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I am just starting out using SQL and trying to figure everything out. Here is the start to my code:

```
SELECT 
Count(DL_Service_ID) AS Group,
Count(DL_Service_ID) AS Individual,
COMPLETED_DATE
FROM DAILY_LOG_DATA 
WHERE Group = '8369' AND Individual = '8219'
AND BETWEEN '2020-04-05' AND '2020-04-11';
```

What I am trying to accomplish is counting the number of services(8369 and 8219) from the column DL_service_ID from the dates 2020-04-05 and 2020-04-11(COMPLETED_DATE). I would like to show the results in separate columns (Individual) which is 8219 and (Group) which is 8369. The dates are shown like this: 2020-04-07 11:14:19 in the COMPLETED_DATE column, not sure if that changes anything. I am also using DBeaver.

Comment: You need a GROUP BY!

Comment: Column aliases can't be used in the WHERE clause.

Comment: `Count(DL_Service_ID)` would count the number of DL_Service_ID values, and that would not be a string (`'8369'`)

Comment: I added some tags, hopefully that is what you are looking for. This is a fairly new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM DAILY_LOG_DATA WHERE DL_Service_ID = '8369'
AND COMPLETED_DATE BETWEEN '2020-04-05' AND '2020-04-11'
GROUP BY DL_Service_ID,COMPLETED_DATE
UNION
SELECT DL_Service_ID AS Individual, Count(DL_Service_ID) AS "Group", COMPLETED_DATE 
FROM DAILY_LOG_DATA WHERE DL_Service_ID = '8219'
AND COMPLETED_DATE BETWEEN '2020-04-05' AND '2020-04-11'
GROUP BY DL_Service_ID,COMPLETED_DATE
```

[image]

Comment: Well I've tried both examples provided and got the same error on both: SQL Error [923] [S1000]: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.

Comment: When looking up this error it tells me this: ORA-00923 occurs when you try to execute a SELECT or REVOKE statement without a FROM keyword in its correct form and place. If you are seeing this error, the keyword FROM is spelled incorrectly, misplaced, or altogether missing. In Oracle, the keyword FROM must follow the last selected item in a SELECT statement or in the case of a REVOKE statement, the privileges. If the FROM keyword is missing or otherwise incorrect, you will see ORA-00923.

Comment: @Babatope.Festus....I tried your solution and am getting an error of SQL Error [936] [S1000]: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00936: missing expression. I did change the alias names from Group > Group_cnt and Individual > Individual_cnt.

Comment: That was why I gave the service_id the Group so that you can use Count as Label. @HopDevvil814 Look at the edited script.

Comment: I tried your edited script and got SQL Error [900] [37000]: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement. Seems like I am overlooking something.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
SELECT COMPLETED_DATE,
       sum( case when DL_Service_ID = '8369' then 1 else 0 end ) AS Group_cnt,
       sum( case when DL_Service_ID = '8219' then 1 else 0 end ) as Individual_cnt
FROM DAILY_LOG_DATA 
WHERE COMPLETED_DATE BETWEEN '2020-04-05' AND '2020-04-11'
GROUP BY COMPLETED_DATE;
```

Comment: Am I missing something? I am getting this error:                                                            SQL Error [923] [S1000]: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.

Comment: @HopDevvil814 . . . You have `GROUP` as a column alias in your question.  It is a really bad choice for a column alias, because it is a SQL keyword.  Use something more appropriate.